# How to figure out stat dependencies of Fighting Skills?

Tags: sakuna-of-rice-and-ruin

How to figure out stat dependencies of Fighting Skills?

The English Wiki list of the [skills](https://sakuna-of-rice-and-ruin.fandom.com/wiki/Fighting_Skills#Skills), and [the Japanese one](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://hyperwiki.jp/sakuna/amagaeshi/) as well, says that certain skills' damage depends on certain stats, like "Frontal Smash" depends on "Strength"... Which I can *guess* at, since its description talks about using "godly might"...

But others depend on Magic or Luck? And nothing in the in-game skill descriptions directly discusses these stat dependencies?

Are there some Scrolls or something else in-game, that directly tells me this apparently hidden info?